# Cmake to generate solution file machine independent

Tags: cmake, gsl

I tried to generate a solution file of GSL library for visual studio 2012 using cmake gui. I did that successfully and I build the library for my own computer. But when I tried to build the same solution file in my different computer, it gives me errors saying "C:/my other computer directory/xxx.vcxproj does not exist" . Is there any way that I can generate sln file which is machine independent.

Comment: If you're trying to build the project on two separate computers, you should run CMake on each to generate their sln files.  CMake generally uses absolute paths, so generated CMake files aren't portable between machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake is not designed to be used in this way, and it is highly unlikely you will be able to use it in this way. CMake performs system introspection, storing this in the CMake cache, and uses full paths to most things. I would advise you to run CMake on each system, and prefer offering simple instructions to run CMake/cmake-gui on each machine.